# Why does Obi-Wan choose the loudest possible transport (a yipping Varactyl) to sneak up on Grievous?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, obi-wan-kenobi

Moments after Obi-Wan gives Grievous the slip by making him believe he's flown off of Utapau when in fact he's stealthily hidden in the shadows, he hops onto a screaming, leaping Varactyl and rides it directly onto the ledge that Grievous was just watching from above (a ledge which is also clearly visible from basically everywhere else in the sinkhole). He knows there are "thousands of battle droids" and that "they are watching us", since he was just told as much by the Pua'an that greeted him when he landed.

**Is he trying to alert Grievous for some reason (and somehow fails to do so), or is he just being incredibly careless?**

Comment: He's a bold one. There's not much making sense of the script overall - I suspect the most likely explanation is that they wanted to sell some "Obi-Wan's mount" toys later...

Comment: I don't think stealth was too much of a concern to him seeing as he jumped right into the middle of his forces and greeted him loudly

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe true - it's hard to understand Obi-Wan's actions on Utapau since he first goes through the subterfuge of making them believe the he's left, then (seemingly) sneaks up on them, then leaps into the middle of their army, seemingly willing to take them on single handed. It's also strange that he doesn't wait for backup to arrive in the form of the Clone Troopers. Possible he just didn't want them to know he was there until he was close and could directly engage them to prevent them escaping.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe that said, it's pretty clear from the accepted answer that stealth was his goal - at least until he'd had a chance to hear their plans: "Besides, if he could get close enough to hear what they were saying, he might find out some of their plans."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The varactyl is a nice choice *on a planet where these are normally found as a mode of transport.*

> All Obi-Wan had to do was find **one of the giant lizards that the
> Utapauans used as riding beasts.** The lizard climbed the sinkhole wall
> easily, and soon Obi-Wan was riding across the edge of the tenth
> level, searching for the control center.
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novelization))</sup></sub>

Sure, it looks crazily conspicuous to you, because you don't often see gigantic lizards jumping around the place on Earth, but on Utapau this is basically the equivalent of a car or a bike.

[image]

And as far as noise is concerned, note that he ditched the lizard, out of earshot of Grievous and his people, specifically so that they wouldn't hear him coming.

> Besides, if he could get close enough to hear what they were saying, he might find out some of their plans. He climbed down from the lizard and slipped along a high, narrow walkway, hoping the sound of their voices would carry once he got near enough.
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novelization))</sup></sub>

Comment: This works. It hadn't occurred to me that these things would be everywhere and it would actually be a way of blending in, but when you put it that way you're absolutely right.